# Google charts "Your browser does not support charts" on Puppeteer

Tags: google-visualization, puppeteer

I've just started using Pupetteer to run some front-end tests on my pages that include Google Charts, and after launching Puppeteer non-headless (`await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})`, I see this error rendered where my chart should be

[image: Your browser does not support charts]

This suprised me as Puppeteer should be basically the same as what I see when I load the page on Chrome, no? Any ideas on how I can fool Google Charts into working on Puppeteer the same as it does when I load the page on Chrome?

I load the Google Charts library with `await google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})`

[How to get angular google-charts to puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606583/how-to-get-angular-google-charts-to-puppeteer) did not help, I still have the problem with `headless: true` (confirmed using a screenshot) and `--disable-web-security`.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was because I had set a custom user-agent, which apparently google charts does not like